# jQuery serialize the form twice (caching serialize ?)

Tags: jquery, caching, serialization

In this URL http://www.juju.runover.com.br/meus-dados, I have a form loaded dinamicaly in the "Bancos" section.
I put an alert to show me the data sent and when I change the "Selecionar banco" option and try to submit, the serialization is duplicated!

Here is my first submit:

```
pessoa=0&cpf_cnpj=40367993805&conta=0082734&conta_digito=7&agencia=0395&agencia_digito=6&tipo=0&id=1&acao=alterar
```

Now, after I've changed the "Selecionar banco" option to "outro..." and again to "itau", this is the result:

```
pessoa=0&cpf_cnpj=40367993805&conta=0082734&conta_digito=7&agencia=0395&agencia_digito=6&tipo=0&id=1&acao=alterar&pessoa=0&cpf_cnpj=40367993805&conta=0082734&conta_digito=7&agencia=0395&agencia_digito=6&tipo=0&id=1&acao=alterar
```

Because of that I can't update the record, because de new data is sent before the old data (the second submit generated)...

I've searched a lot, tried serializeArray, and nothing

The Serialization Code:

```
jQuery('#banco').live('submit', function () {
    var dados = jQuery('#banco').serialize();
    alert(dados);

    /*
    jQuery.post(
        'app/painel/form/form_banco.php',
        dados,
        function (data) {
            alert(data);
            atualizaLista();
        }
    );
    */
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that does the serializing?

Comment: @ExplosionPills it's a jQuery method - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two forms with the same id: "banco"

```
This is what I got from the console:
$("#banco")

[
<form id=​"banco" class=​"row-fluid" method=​"post" action>​…​</form>​
, 
<form id=​"banco" class=​"row-fluid" method=​"post" action>​…​</form>​
]
```

You need to change the id of the forms.